# Showing partial derivatives of $x^3/{(x^2+y^2)}$ are bounded

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

> Show that the partial derivatives of $x^3/{x^2+y^2}$ are bounded. Find if they are continuous.

I calculated the partial derivatives to be 
$${\partial f\over\partial x}={x^2(3y^2+x^2)\over(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
$${\partial f\over\partial y}={-2x^3y\over(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

But I'm not sure how to show that they are bounded and/or continuous

Comment: For continuity you can use that they are formed by the composition of continuous functions everywhere were defined. Now you are left with checking whether the functions are continuous where the denominator vanishes, as here they are not defined at first.

Comment: Check your derivative wrt $x$ again, if I'm not mistaken your numerator should be $x^2(x^2+3y^2)$.

Comment: @Kevin There will be atleast one negative sign since we are diff denominator as well

Comment: @Anvit If we write $f=u/v$ then $f' = (v \mathrm{d}u-u \mathrm{d}v)/v^2$ hence the numerator would be $3x^2(x^2+y^2)-x^3(2x) = 3x^4+3x^2 y^2-2x^4 = x^4+3x^2 y^2$

Comment: @Kevin, I see my error now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your calculations are correct, you can simply divide top and bottom by $x^4$ to obtain

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{x^2(3y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{3r^2-1}{(1+r^2)^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{-2x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{-2r}{(1+r^2)^2}$$

where $r = \frac yx$. Then prove that the RHS is bounded for $r \in [0,\infty)$ by differentiating with respect to $r$ and finding the extremum.